# Need advice on SVN for web development

Tags: svn, version-control

We have for the longest time, and still, not been using any sort of version control system at my workplace, and I have now demanded that we get to use this. Since we have some free time at the moment, the boss has ordered me to implement it, but I don't know enough about it to be sure how to implement it correctly.

First let me illustrate our current setup:

[image: Current setup]

With the current setup, when me or my colleague needs to work in a file, we actually need to ask each other if the other are working in the file I'm about to open etc. This is not good, and I believe a tool like SVN is what we need. Git is currently not an option.

I'm currently not sure how to set SVN up correctly in our situation, and I would like to do this and use this correctly from the beginning.

How would you suggest we do this ?

My initial thought was a setup that involved both Computer A and Computer B each running a local webserver, which me and my colleague each developed on, and commit to a "master" developer webserver, when done.. But I don't think this is the most correct or best way, since I'm not sure what to do about database, nor what to do when moving from the development server to the production server.

Comment: Why is git not an option? If you presently have no version control system, all options should be on the table. In any case, this is a *very* broad topic (broader than can be answered here, as you're starting with a blank slate) and there are *many* ways to solve this problem. The keywords you're looking for are continuous integration/deployment software and methods, as well as automated deployment tools/practices.

Comment: 1. Too broad 2. SCM is **process**, not action 3. Free blind remote consultation isn't good option at all - you'll have a lot of cases not covered